# Does alcohol really helps to get substances into the blood faster?

Tags: nutrition, supplements, alcohol

I saw [the video](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=schwarzenegger%20shnapps&t=brave&iax=videos&ia=videos&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D4AqIzkThbqE) where Arnold Schwarzenegger cooks some protein cocktail and adds Austrian Schnapps to the mix, saying that it's to make everything get faster to the blood.
Is it true or some kind of a joke?

Comment: If you want to discuss the content of a video, it would help if you linked it.

Comment: @Alec I've done it.

Comment: Alcohol inhibits protein synthesis, which is necessary for muscle building.
It affects Glucose, which is needed for energy and recovery, so in this aspect itll stunt your recovery and energy.
For workouts, it dilates your blood vessels forcing blood into limbs and leaving core colder, what this means is that you'll loose performance. The article mentions that this mainly affects endurance

Comment: Who knows why it's off-topic, it's clearly question about fitness.

Comment: @RS Nutrition questions not directly related to fitness, are considered off-topic. This is for several reasons including the fact that we don't have nutrition experts visiting this site and it is very difficult to test nutrition advice on yourself. Your question in particular is only related to fitness in that you reference Arnold. It's really a biology question. Maybe if you asked "If I drink schnapps with my protein powder, will my bench press max improve?" that would be accepted, but do you think anyone really knows the answer to that? They might have an opinion, but they don't know.